# How to dismantle a shower frame with screws close to the wall, facing the wall?

Tags: shower, screws

I need to remove a shower frame. It seems that I first need to remove the top horizontal bar. It is, however, screwed from the inside of vertical frames. How can I unscrew them and then screw back? Unscrewing seems hard enough, but even if I do that it seems they once I try to screw them back the first thing they'll do is fall inside the vertical bar.

Upper right corner, seen from the outside:

[image: Upper right corner of the frame.]

View from the top opening:

[image: Inside view from the opening]

The width of the opening, and thus distance of the screw heads to the wall is around 8 cm.

Comment: An angle screwdriver should work, might still be a pain in the neck.  To block from falling, a rag stuff down below the screws, and/or a magnet should work.

Comment: A Chapman set is what I use a short bit with a small ratchet, both screws have to be backed out and the part moved so the screws don’t trap the bit.

Comment: I have manual angled screwdrivers and a right-angle bit attachment for my drill that takes the 1/4 bits. Both work well.

Comment: Doesn't the vertical framing, door and wall, come apart?

Comment: Before attempting that painful job, look on the inside of the vertical sections of the frame for screws you can remove there. If those are present, they will let you slide the entire frame side-to-side, allowing you to remove it in one piece.

Comment: @brhans Ahh, that must be it! Thanks. Will try now and report back.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @brhans and @JACK

These screws holding the vertical frame should come off only when the entire frame is removed, which can be done by fist unscrewing screws on the vertical bars.

Front view:

```
/++--+------------+--++/
/||  |(hrzntl bar)|  ||/
/||  +------------+  ||/
/|| x|            |x ||/
/||  |            |  ||/
/||  |            |  ||/
/|| x|            |x ||/
/||  |            |  ||/
/||  |            |  ||/
/|| x|            |x ||/
/||  |            |  ||/
/||  |            |  ||/
/|| x|            |x ||/
/||  +------------+  ||/
/||  |            |  ||/
/++--+------------+--++/
```

First I needed to unscrew the `x` screws on the vertical bars.

This allowed me to slide the entire frame to side and remove, because it's constructed like this:

Top view of region attaching to the wall:

```
\    ---------++------------~
\+-------     ||  (horizontal bar)
\|(wall att-  || 
##X chmnt)   X###  <-(the impossible-to-unscrew-screws from the photo)
\|            ||
\+-----#--    ||
\    --#------++------------~
\      x  <-(vertical screws to remove first,
\             will allow horizontal movement when removed)
```

Comment: Nice ASCII-art ;)